# Problema em Validação de Login e Senha Java/SQL

Tags: java, sql

Estou com um problema na validação de Login e Senha, o código só está pegado os valores da primeira linha do banco de dados, mas quando tento colocar os valores das outras linhas ele dá erro, agradeço se alguém conseguir me ajudar. Segue o código abaixo.

```
try{
    Connection con = BancoSQL.getConexao();
    String sql = "select Login, Senha from cadfuncionario";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

    String login = jUsuario.getText();
    String senha = jSenha.getText();

    while(rs.next()){

        if(rs.getString("Login").equalsIgnoreCase(login) 
        && rs.getString("Senha").equalsIgnoreCase(senha)){

            this.dispose();
            MenuP m = new MenuP();
            m.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bem vindo");
            break;

        }else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario ou Senha Incorretos!");
            jUsuario.setText("");
            jSenha.setText("");
        }

    }
    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro que você aproveite o PreparedStatement e faça o seguinte:

```
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("select idusuario from usuario where login = ? and senha = ?");
p.setString(1, login);
p.setString(2, senha);
ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();

if(r.next()){
    // Se r.next() for verdade existe uma combinação login/senha               
}

// Nunca esqueça de fechar os fluxos, eles podem acumular.
r.close();
p.close();
con.close();
```

Assim o banco de dados retornará apenas uma linha, não precisaria percorrer todas as linhas da sua tabela de cadastro (Não faz muito sentido já que não deve haver 2 combinações login/senha iguais). Além disso, essas "?" do prepared protegem contra SQL injection.

Obs.: Evite guardar senhas em plain text no banco, guarde apenas senhas criptografadas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, ao que parece:

```
if(rs.getString("Login").equalsIgnoreCase(login) 
 && rs.getString("Senha").equalsIgnoreCase(senha)){
```

Ao entrar nesse bloco do código a primeira vez, você chama o comando

```
 break;
```

fazendo o código sair do `while(rs.next())` e acabando a execução do teu aplicativo. Ou seja, mesmo que tenha mais de um resultado sempre acabará na primeira linha.